# GetAsyncKeyState not working when typing on "Run as Administrator" application

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, keylogger

I write a simple Win32 Keylogger application by C++ in Windows. like this [text](https://github.com/EgeBalci/Keylogger/blob/master/Source.cpp)

I use GetAsyncKeyState to check key state and log that key to a file

```
char KEY = 'x';

while (true) {
    Sleep(10);
    for (int KEY = 8; KEY <= 190; KEY++)
    {
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(KEY) == -32767) {
            if (SpecialKeys(KEY) == false) {

                fstream LogFile;
                LogFile.open("dat.txt", fstream::app);
                if (LogFile.is_open()) {
                    LogFile << char(KEY);
                    LogFile.close();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I run my program with my user account. When I open notepad and start typing, It logs every key which I typed. But if I open notepad with "Run as Administrator" option, then nothing get logged.

How can I fix this?

Comment: IIRC the admin application is running in a higher security context.  If you could read the keyboard messages of a higher security application that would be a breach of security.  If you need to read all keystrokes consider installing a keyboard hook.

Comment: So, If I run a program with admin account then  Keylogger can't log. Right? @RichardCritten

Comment: Side note: According to the official Microsoft documentation for the function [`GetAsyncKeyState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate), the information in the low-order bit of the return value is unreliable and only provided for backward compatibility. In the line `GetAsyncKeyState(KEY) == -32767`, you are also checking the value of this unreliable bit. However, this is probably not the reason for your problem.

Comment: Logins occur in the secure desktop, it stops any attempt at looking at keyboard input, regardless of account privileges.  This is a feature of course.

Comment: Even if you could get this working, note that a GetAsyncKeyState() loop is just too unstable to work as a viable key logger. You really need a keyboard hook instead, either from SetWindowsHookEx() or RegisterRawInputDevices()